# Why lambda execution doesn't emit events related to result?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Why lambda execution doesn't emit event related to result?
Unlike lambda, glue or batch emit event related to result (success, fail)
I am really curious about it.

I want to use event for triggering other service

I am using lambda in step function and I invoke it synchronously.
So I can't use "destination"

I think I should use boto 3 code in lambda to putEvent or
inset putEvent in state function..

Why lambda execution doesn't emit event related to result??

Comment: Hi Sandra, Welcome to Stack Overflow! As currently written, this question is a bit off topic. It is basically asking "Why does a 3rd party service do what it does/is designed the way it is designed?". Instead, I would suggest updating your question to something more along the lines of "how do I emit events from an AWS Lambda Function". Include what you have tried so far (minimal code example) for best results. 

I would also suggest a few resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You may also be interested in SNS, SQS, and Step Functions.